# Photoshop how to create a box with curved edges and a background color easily

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

[image: Picture that needs perfect curved edges]

As you can see in this picture, the edges are very rough because ive used the the brushes with background color. What I want to achieve is the perfect curve for this angle. I tried to edit the brush settings but it's too complicated for me. Is there any easy way to do this that doesnt involve creating the curve with a mouse because that seems impossible for me.

Thanks

Comment: I wonder what you mean by your last sentence, because you are going to have to use a mouse, if you want this done. It won't magically draw itself. What you should use is the [Pen tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/drawing-pen-tools.html)

Comment: It *is* near impossible if you use a mouse and a brush... so I see that point... it's very easy with the mouse and the Pen Tool as Joonas suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joonas noted in his comment, use the pen tool to create precise curved shapes. The pen tool uses vectors - mathematically defined shapes that can be styled by fills and strokes - to create precise artwork that can be scaled to any size without loss of resolution. They are resolution-independent - although when displayed on screen you may still see "pixelation" as this is an artifact of your screen rendering a vector graphic and not of the actual vector graphic itself.

In Adobe's software packages (Illustrator, InDesign, Photoshop), these vector tools use bezier formulas to determine the curves - thus you may hear them referred to as bezier curves, bezier points, etc.

Comment: I guess this video explains it well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSdov7nVYdo